# Spring 4 Controller not converting JSON to Java class

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I'm tryng to convert JSON into a java class using Spring. 
When I execute the code I get 400 bad request.
If I replace User java object (`@RequestBody final **User** user`) with generic java Oject (`@RequestBody final **Object** user`), I get the json string as parameter.

Here's my code.

Javascript:

```
register : function(usr,pwd) {
    var user = {username : usr, password: pwd}
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/SpringSecurityRememberMeAnnotationExample/newuser',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:user
    });
    /*
    return $http.post('/SpringSecurityRememberMeAnnotationExample/newuser', user).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
    */
},
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody public User SaveUser(@RequestBody final User user){
        System.out.println("username: ");// + user.username);
        System.out.println("password: ");// + user.password);
        return null;
    }
```

spring-mvc.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<!-- Login Interceptor -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.websystique.springsecurity.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <!-- workaround to fix IE8 problem -->
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- i18n -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/i18n"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="fileEncodings" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="it"/>
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
</bean>

<!-- Exception handler -->
<bean id="exceptionResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
  <property name="exceptionMappings">
    <props>
      <prop key="LoginRequiredException">          
        public/loginRequired
      </prop>
      <prop key="ResourceNotFoundException">          
        public/notFound
      </prop>
    </props>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultErrorView" value="rescues/general" />
</bean>

<!-- View Handler -->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thank you!

Adding POM.XML config, json part

```
<!-- JSon -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: put double quotes around `username ` and `password` when you are creating json in js.

Comment: @OAD I tryed to change js into var user = {"username" : usr, "password": pwd}; but still not working

Comment: Remove the `jacksonMessageConverter` and the `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`. Those are configured automatically.

Comment: @francesco can you show me the `User` class I think you dont have propper setter getters.

Comment: Also you are mixing jackson versions remove the `1.9.13` stuff.

Comment: @OAD you're right. The issue is in the User class because it was inside the controller. Once I did it's own User.java file in it's own package, it starts to work properly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @M. Deinum I've cleaned up the dependencies and the spring.xml file. All is working. Thank you

Comment: @FrancescoDiPasquantonio i have answered it, so accept it so that other users can also get benefit for such problem. thanks

Comment: The user class inside the controller shouldn't matter if it would be a `static class` and not a `class`.

Comment: @M. Deinum unfortunately it was not a `static class`, then it was not working. Now it's fine because I put it in the right package. I'll check for documentation to understand why `static` is fine and non static not when inside the controller. Thank you!

Comment: A non-static interclass requires an instance of the enclosing class to be created before it itself van be created. This is not the case with a static inner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Problem was on the User class embedded on the controller code. Once I created User.java file on it's own package all goes smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

Recheck the setters/getters for the fields and make sure there is a no-argument constructor. (If you have no constructor, Java will generate a default no-arg one, but if you have added a constructor with arguments yourself, you must take care to implement a no-arg one as well).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing malformed json object i  guess. you should pass user json data like below.

```
var user = {"username" : "<username>", "password": "<password>"};
```

And makes sure `User.java` has setters/getters for the fields and default constructor.

Comment: I tryed to build string as you suggested but doesn't works.    var user = {username : '<' + usr + '>', password: '<' + pwd + '>'}

Comment: names in json data should be enclosed with double quotes. i.e. var user={"username": usr, "password":pwd}; before invoking the rest service try to print data in alert dialog and see.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure following two jars are present in your application

***1. Jackson - core

 2. Jackson - mapper***

Both Java API are used by spring for XML/JSON processing.

Comment: I put my pom.xml, I updated jackson lib to the latest version since I'm using spring 4, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

put  `var user = {"username" : usr, "password": pwd};` in java script,
 and do confirm that your `User` class is right having proper setter getter and proper access to your calling class.